# Get all permutations with duplicate numbers but not duplicate sets

Tags: javascript

e.g. given `[1,2,2]` the output should be

```
[
    [1],
    [2],
    [2,2],
    [1,2],
    [1,2,2],
]
```

So, `2` is allowed to appear in the same output twice because it's in the input twice, but `[1,(first 2)]` and `[1,(second 2)]` are *not* considered distinct.

I figured out how to do it treating each element as unique:

```
function *getPermutations(arr) {
    if(arr.length === 1) {
        yield arr;
    } else if(arr.length === 2) {
        yield arr;
        yield [arr[0]];
        yield [arr[1]];
    } else if(arr.length >= 3) {
        const left = arr.slice(0,2);
        const right = arr.slice(2);

        for(const l of getPermutations(left)) {
            yield l;
            for(const r of getPermutations(right)) {
                yield l.concat(r);
            }
        }

        for(const r of getPermutations(right)) {
            yield r;
        }
    }
}
```

But now I'm trying to figure out if there's an algorithm for doing it without the duplicate sets.

Is this possible from within `getPermutations` or should I just write a 2nd function to remove the duplicate sets?